# Bulk insert skips one of the fields in the iinput file

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

Working here on bulk insert, which skips 2 records. Explanation below:

```
My table (works fine, Auto-incrementing Job_Id):



create table avjobs ( Job_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
Job_Name varchar(255), Job_Seq varchar(255), Job_Date varchar(255), 
Start_Time time, End_Time time, Runtime time, Status varchar(255) );
```

Here is my csv file:

```
JOB1A|0029|20140506|14:01:05|15:00:01|0:59:45|FINISHED
JOB2B|0030|20140506|15:01:05|16:00:01|0:59:55|INITIATED
```

Here is the BULK INSERT that I am using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/jobs.csv' INTO TABLE avjobs FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 9 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Here is output for select:

```
mysql> select * from avjobs;
+--------+----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+----------+--------+
| Job_Id | Job_Name | Job_Seq  | Job_Date | Start_Time | End_Time | Runtime  | Status |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+----------+--------+
|      1 | 0029     | 20140506 | 14:01:05 | 15:00:01   | 00:23:55 | 00:00:00 | NULL   |
|      2 | 0030     | 20140506 | 15:01:05 | 16:00:01   | 00:59:55 | 00:00:00 | NULL   |
+--------+----------+----------+----------+------------+----------+----------+--------+
```

The Bulk insert skips, somehow, the job name as well as status.

Can you please advise what is wrong in syntax?

Comment: What happens if you put a `|` at the end of each line in the csv?

Comment: Possibly helpful: "If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use LINES TERMINATED BY `'\r\n'` to read the file properly..." -- [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when asking your questions. It makes them harder to read, it's rather annoying, and it won't get you help any faster. The Shift key is available on both sides of your keyboard to make sure you can reach it. Please do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify your columns:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/jobs.csv' 
INTO TABLE avjobs (Job_Name, Job_Seq, Job_Date, Start_Time, End_Time, Runtime, Status)    
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

because your import file doesn't contain your Job_ID, see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

> LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata; By default,
>   when no column list is provided at the end of the LOAD DATA INFILE
>   statement, input lines are expected to contain a field for each table
>   column. If you want to load only some of a table's columns, specify a
>   column list: